# Using AsymmetricAlgorithm Private and Public key with RSA C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, public-key, private-key

I have two AsymmetricAlgorithm objects that contain an RSA Private and RSA Public key. The private key was retrieved out of the Windows-MY keystore and the Public key from a user's certificate. How can I use these keys along with RSACryptoServiceProvider to encrypt data using the RSA algorithm in C#? In other words, how can I specify that I want to use keys that I already have?

Comment: You could get better answers when you include some details about those 'two objects'.

Comment: They are matching RSA keys that I pulled out of user certificates, what else is there to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#region "RSA Encrypt/Decrypt"  
public string RSAEncrypt(string str, string publicKey)  
{  
  //---Creates a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider---  
  try {  
     RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();  
     //---Loads the public key---  
     RSA.FromXmlString(publicKey);  
     byte[] EncryptedStr = null;  

     //---Encrypts the string---  
     EncryptedStr = RSA.Encrypt(ASCII.GetBytes(str), false);  
     //---Converts the encrypted byte array to string---  
     int i = 0;  
     System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();  
     for (i = 0; i <= EncryptedStr.Length - 1; i++) {  
         //Console.WriteLine(EncryptedStr(i))  
         if (i != EncryptedStr.Length - 1) {  
             s.Append(EncryptedStr[i] + " ");  
         } else {  
             s.Append(EncryptedStr[i]);  
         }  
     }  

     return s.ToString();  
   } catch (Exception err) {  
     Interaction.MsgBox(err.ToString());  
   }  
}  

public string RSADecrypt(string str, string privateKey)  
{  
  try {  
     //---Creates a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider---  
     RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();  
     //---Loads the private key---  
     RSA.FromXmlString(privateKey);  

     //---Decrypts the string---  
     byte[] DecryptedStr = RSA.Decrypt(HexToByteArr(str), false);  
     //---Converts the decrypted byte array to string---  
     System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();  
     int i = 0;  
     for (i = 0; i <= DecryptedStr.Length - 1; i++) {  
         //Console.WriteLine(DecryptedStr(i))  
         s.Append(System.Convert.ToChar(DecryptedStr[i]));  
     }  
     //Console.WriteLine(s)  
     return s.ToString();  
  } catch (Exception err) {  
     Interaction.MsgBox(err.ToString());  
  }  
}  
#endregion
```

The Public Key (arg) should look like this:
    <RSAKeyValue>
      <Modulus>yNi8BvATA77f+/6cU6z[...]9VULgU=</Modulus>
      <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    </RSAKeyValue>

The Private Key (arg) should look like this:
    <RSAKeyValue>
      <Modulus>yNi8BvATA77f+/6cU6z[...]9VULgU=</Modulus>
      <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
      <P>8ZlZPmko3sam9pvD/l[...]ba0MWLjj9dyUMvmTQ6L8m9IQ==</P>
      <Q>1NGHjXyEa9SjUwY[...]v+op2YyyglMeK/Gt5SL0v6xqQZQ==</Q>
      <DP>LpjE/aSKnWzzBt1E[...]i5f63Ak9wVG3ZPnwVDwefNkMAQ==</DP>
      <DQ>qAgb8AGNiJom[...]8x3qaD3wx+UbnM5v3aE5Q==</DQ>
      <InverseQ>fQ4+7r3Nmgvz113L[...]uJqEgCNzw==</InverseQ>
      <D>B4n7JNeGHzHe/nqEK[...]GaOBtuz0QTgE=</D>
    </RSAKeyValue>

Comment: Cool, i can use AsymmetricAlgorithm.ToXmlString(bool) to convert the keys to XML. Thanks.

Comment: -1, sorry, this example is bad enough to lead future people astray. There is no need to specialize to strings, less of a need to specialize to ASCII strings, it doesn't decrypt the format that it outputs from its encrypt method, and includes an unspecified method HexToByteArr().

Comment: @gregs, you are kinda picky amigo.  I built these two functions a few years ago because it is easier to encrypt/decrypt (ascii) strings than byte[].  It demonstrates the concept.  Converting Hex to byte[] is pretty fundamental, so I didn't include irrellevant code here.  A quick search of "HexToBytes" yields plenty of examples.