# Get Private Key From AsymmetricAlgorithm

Tags: c#, encryption

How can I get the private key from AsymmetricAlgorithm.ToXmlString() ?

The XML string just has a bunch of nodes. I'm not sure what they all mean:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>
    kepPAzfA0xSF...
  </Modulus>
  <Exponent>
    AQAB
  </Exponent>
  <P>
    vSUa7Lw...
  </P>
  <Q>
    xX2KSkvg...
  </Q>
  <DP>
    XQD+wUM...
  </DP>
  <DQ>
    fxHfwR5B...
  </DQ>
  <InverseQ>
    Zpmx1El6...
  </InverseQ>
  <D>
    BOgHtMhTeoWDzn...
  </D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

EDIT:
C# code:

```
    string pfxFilePath = @"C:\temp\someCert.pfx";
    string pfxPassword = "somePassword";
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxFilePath, pfxPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    string privateKey = cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);//This has the xml code above
```

Comment: Can you post some of your C# code?

Comment: Might [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206660/using-asymmetricalgorithm-private-and-public-key-with-rsa-c-sharp) be of any use to you?